# Pig JsonLoader() bug?

Tags: json, apache-pig

I am trying to load a json file with pig. I can load the file succesfully, but i found a bug.

```
schema:
id,name,brand,color
```

data:

```
{"id":2561,"name":"abc","brand":"Levis","color":"Blue"}
{"id":2562,"brand":"Adidas","color":"Black"}
{"id":2563,"name":"edf","brand":"Nike","color":"White"}
```

code:

```
raw = LOAD '$INPUT_PATH' USING JsonLoader('
id:chararray,
name:chararray,
brand:chararray,
color:chararray
');

x = foreach raw generate id,brand;
dump x;
```

And result is wrong if the particular raw does no contains all the fields defined in the schema: (the second raw should be Adidas instead of black)

```
(2561,Levis)
(2562,Black)
(2563,Nike)
```

Is there any workaround for the above?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use `elephantbird` instead of `JsonLoader`. `Elephantbird`  will store the input json in the form of `key/value pair(i.e map)` and it will be easy to extract the required fields even-though some fields are missing in the input json.

Download the two jars files(`elephant-bird-pig-4.1.jar` and `elephant-bird-hadoop-compat-4.1.jar`) and try the below approach.

**input.json**

```
{"id":2561,"name":"abc","brand":"Levis","color":"Blue"}
{"id":2562,"brand":"Adidas","color":"Black"}
{"id":2563,"name":"edf","brand":"Nike","color":"White"}
```

**PigScript:**

```
REGISTER /tmp/elephant-bird-pig-4.1.jar;
REGISTER /tmp/elephant-bird-hadoop-compat-4.1.jar;

A = LOAD 'input.json' USING com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader() AS myMap;
B = FOREACH A GENERATE myMap#'id' AS ID,myMap#'brand' AS brand;
DUMP B;
```

**Output:**

```
(2561,Levis)
(2562,Adidas)
(2563,Nike)
```